# Can I connect to the console of a Cisco 2960 switch via ethernet cable?

Tags: cisco

I believe I need a serial to USB converter but would like to know if it is possible to connect to the console with just a regular Cat5e ethernet cable as my laptop doesn't have a serial port and I don't have an adapter handy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the ethernet port on your laptop doesn't speak the same language as the RJ-45 serial console port despite having the same connector; you'll need the serial adapter.

Comment: That's what I figured but wanted to ask just in case. Wishful thinking I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Some 2960's have the micro USB port.  You can use any mini usb cable and get in with Hyperterminal.  You just need the "Cisco_usbconsole_driver.zip".

Comment: 2960S switches have a *mini* USB port that can be used for the console. 2960 (no S) switches only have the RJ-45 serial console.